# JavaScript not working in IE but works in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
post_form_id        = escape(findelementbyname("post_form_id"));
fb_dtsg         = escape(document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value);
cookie_user_uid     = document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1];
xhpc_composerid     = escape(findelementbyname("xhpc_composerid"));
```

It seems as if post_form_id and fb_dtsg cannot execute properly in Internet explorer, but work in Firefox?

What would I have to change to have it working in both?

Comment: Can you elaborate...? How's it broken? Do you get errors?

Comment: What does `findelementbyname` do and return?

Comment: 1) you dont have error info 2) you are using non standard functions, but not giving us the function definitions 3) javascript is case sensitive, you seem to be mixing cases and expecting it to work 4) if you want good answers to javascript questions, make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't think the "ajax" tag is appropriate on this question that seems to only contain plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One Question : Are you able to search by Id instead?  If so, getElementById(...) will be a better choice.

To get elements by name, you will use getElementsByName("...") - but that will return an array of elements, from which you will need to take the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you describe regarding inconsistency across browsers is caused by syntax problems...

I believe that this:

```
findelementbyname(...)
```

should be this:

```
FindElementByName(...)
```

Also run your code through [an online syntax checker like JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Although you can make javascript cross browser compatible without extra libraries (such as JQuery), it can often become unneccesarily painful to do so.
I would recommend the use of JQuery.

Comment: Why the down vote?  An explanation to accompany it would be less cowardly.

Comment: @Chris - I didn't give the down-vote, but my guess would be because your answer doesn't actually answer the question, and would probably have been more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Chris - was not me either but your suggestion of using jQuery avoids the question.

Comment: His issue was not just that his javascript was broken, but rather that it was only broken in a particular browser.  The use of proper libs is extremely useful for avoiding cross browser issues.

Comment: people should be allowed to ask questions about javascript, and people who understand javascript should be the ones to answer them. Unfortunately, the people who know javascript are few in number, and the people who think jquery == javascript are a raging horde. That means most js questions here get jquery answers, which is totally wrong. It is actually pretty normal for answers like this to get downvoted.

Comment: @Chris Rogers:  Saying _"the use of **proper** libs..."_ infers that a library is somehow mandatory.  Simply using the correct JavaScript syntax reduces many cross-browser quirks and IE errors.  You can't fix bad programming by throwing jQuery at it!

Comment: @Matt - Thanks for the explanation.  Being relatively new to SO, your comment was far more educational to me than an anonymous downvote, from which I learn nothing.  I was able to provide a strictly JS answer (and did), but I assumed that pointing out helpful alternatives would be a valid response in S.O.  Obviously not.

Comment: @Sparky : No, that would be the wrong inference. Obviously they're not mandatory. Throwing *anything* at it can't fix bad programming (even correct JS will not do that). But if a new developer is having trouble getting a simple value from an input, then I would have thought the most helpful approach would be to arm them with options which they might find easier to use.

Comment: @Chris Rogers:  I know you were only trying to be helpful but Matt's explanation is spot on.  There are obvious problems with the OP's JS code that should take priority within any answer.  IMHO, I think your jQuery suggestion would have been better within a comment on the original question instead.  (This is only a high quality Q & A site because of user enforcement of strict protocols.)

Comment: @Chris: Adding the jQuery bit as well as a js answer would have been fine, as would leaving the jquery bit as a comment. It is more that "use jQuery" by itself isnt really an answer to this sort of question. Usually answers like that arent downvoted, but specifically the jq ones are, again, just cause they are so common here.